# Как правильно записать в базу массив из данных не по названию их полей, а по id полей, которые хранятся в другой таблице?

Tags: php, mysql, массивы

Есть входящий массив из данныех

```
$inputData = array(
'name'=>'Иван',
'lastname'='>Иванов',
.... еще около сотни полей
'useroffice'=>'5600023-15'
);
```

Хочу поместить эти данные в **таблицу 2** с полями

autoinkrement, fid, value, uid
где

- autoinkrement - просто порядковый номер записи в в таблице
- fid - id поля
- value -  значение поля
- uid - id пользователя

fid полей хранятся в третьей **таблице 3**

```
fid|f_name    |
---------------
1  |name      |
2  |lastname  |
...|...       |
121|useroffice|
```

следовательно **таблица 2** должна выглядеть так

```
autoinkrement|fid|value     |uid
    ---------------
1            |1  |Иван      |87
2            |2  |Иванов    |87
...          |...|...       |87
526          |121|5600023-15|87
```

Так вот как мне поместить fidы  в **таблицу 2**?

В голове сейчас крутится вариант выкачать массив полей из **таблицы 3** назовем его `$fidsArr`

потом запустить перебор массива `$inputData` в котором я буду вытаскивать **ключ** затем запускать перебор массива `$fidsArr` в котором я буду сравнивать значение `f_name` с **ключем** и если совпадает, получать fid, с которым я и буду записывать данные в **таблицу 2**.

Костыль мне кажется в том, что перебор второго массива придется запускать на каждой итерации при переборе первого массива.

То есть если в обоих массивах по 500 значений, то неслабая такая нагрузка выходит.

вот пример данных из второго массива из **таблицы 3**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fid] => 1
            [f_name] => last_name
            [f_status] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [fid] => 2
            [f_name] => name
            [f_status] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [fid] => 3
            [f_name] => otchestvo
            [f_status] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [fid] => 4
            [f_name] => sex
            [f_status] => 1
        )
```

может быть есть способ получить нужный fid из второго массива не прибегая к его перебору?

Comment: Получите из __таблицы 3__ массив где ключ - `f_name`, а значение - `f_id`.

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо! ну вот из таблицы выводится массив только в таком виде, может быть текущий можно как то переформатировать чтобы `f_name` был ключем а `f_id` значением? Статус в принципе не нужен в рамках этой задачи, тоже в голове одно решение, перебрать и собрать новый массив как надо. Но не знаю костыль ли это.. Или может есть готовая функция

Comment: Ну так когда обходите таблицу - сформируйте нужный массив. Если массив откуда-то со стороны приходит - ну обойдите еще раз его.